# Binding ItemsControl to ScrollViewer

Tags: wpf, itemscontrol, scrollviewer, itemssource

At the begining I'll show some code:

```
private ObservableCollection<otwarteBezStolika> otwarteBezStolika = new ObservableCollection<otwarteBezStolika>();

        public ObservableCollection<otwarteBezStolika> listunia
        {
            get { return otwarteBezStolika; }
            set { otwarteBezStolika = value; }
        }
    }
    public class otwarteBezStolika
    {
        public string number { get; set; }
        public string date { get; set; }
        public int orderID { get; set; }
        public decimal price { get; set; }
        public decimal priceR { get; set; }
        public string opisRach { get; set; }
        public string sum { get; set; }
    }
```

And now in xaml:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="dataTempl">
        <Border BorderBrush="Coral" BorderThickness="1" Width="170">
            <Button Name="goToPOS" Tag="{Binding orderID}" Click="goToPOS_Click" Style="{StaticResource TabCloseButtonStyle}" Margin="1">
                <StackPanel>
                    <Label Content="{Binding number}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontSize="15" FontWeight="ExtraBold" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"></Label>
                    <Border BorderBrush="Turquoise" BorderThickness="1" Width="170"></Border>
                    <Label Content="{Binding date}" FontSize="12" HorizontalAlignment="Center"></Label>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding opisRach}" FontStyle="Italic" FontSize="12" Foreground="Black" TextAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="0,0,0,2"></TextBlock>
                    <Border BorderBrush="WhiteSmoke" BorderThickness="1" Width="170"></Border>
                    <Label Content="{Binding sum}" FontSize="19" HorizontalAlignment="Center"></Label>
                </StackPanel>
            </Button>
        </Border>
    </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="mainTemplate">
        <StackPanel>

            <ItemsControl x:Name="imageContent" ItemsSource="{Binding listunia}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource dataTempl}" >
                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" />
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            </ItemsControl>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
```

Grid:

```
<Grid Grid.Row="0">
        <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
            <ItemsControl Name="templ" ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=UI, Path=listunia }" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource mainTemplate}" />
        </ScrollViewer>
    </Grid>
```

Problem is that I cannot see any item (I'm filling items using sqldatareader, and adding them to list - by the way, does DataTable will also work? So instead while(rdr.Read()) i could ouse SqlDataAdapter sda and sda.fill(Datatable))

Second problem is that, it does work when I put "dataTempl" inside scrollviewer ,like :

```
<Grid Grid.Row="0">
        <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
            <ItemsControl Name="templ" ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=UI, Path=listunia }" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource dataTempl}" />
        </ScrollViewer>
    </Grid>
```

but items are show vertically, but I need to see them from left to right horizontal.

Thanks for answers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try doing this.. you dont need maintemplate.

```
<ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
  <ItemsControl Name="templ" ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=UI, Path=listunia }" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource dataTempl}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
          <ItemsPanelTemplate>
               <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" />
           </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
  </ItemsControl>
</ScrollViewer>
```

OR you can simply use:

```
  <ListBox Name="templ" ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=UI, Path=listunia }" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource dataTempl}">
  </ListBox>
```

Comment: Ok, it does show item now - but only one on the middle of the screen :) I've changed that StackPanel widht and height to 150/70, and Im sure it should show more, becouse "listunia" have 71 items

Comment: is it the valid one? how many items do you have? how are you setting the datacontext of the view? and last one what is element "UI" :)?

Comment: Sorry, 76 not 71. I can show them right using vertical/horizontal aligment, but it looks like scrollviewer width isnt set properly. Items now showint like: 
[][][][][][][][][][][][][][], not like [][][][] "enter" [][][][] "enter" [][][][] "enter" [][][][]:)

Comment: why dont you use the simple listbox instead without any itemspanel? also dont use scrollviewer...itemscontrol will show its autoscroll by itself..

Comment: It cannot be listview, becouse i have proper style for each item. It have to be 'button' with stackPanel inside (which shows information etc) so after click will go to another window. Yea, i know that I can use selectionchanged in listview, but i'd like to leave it like this - as buttons. But still showing them wrong, as I said post before :)

Comment: try using the updated answer.. it is same as using ItemsControl as ListBox is itself ItemsControl..and u can have anything in item also.. u just need to update your itemtemplate to have it

Comment: Got it. Instead of StackPanel I should use WrapPanel. Now items are shown just the way I wanted it to be ;) Thanks +1 and marked as answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
<ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
        <ItemsControl Name="kaloo" DisplayMemberPath="Name" ss:DragDrop.IsDragSource="True" ss:DragDrop.IsDropTarget="True"  >
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <WrapPanel />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
 </ScrollViewer>
```